# Mount of File System Failed. -- After upgrading from 9.04 to 9.10

Tags: mount, grub2

After upgrading from Ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10 I am getting this message on boot up:

> Mount of File System Failed. A
>   maintenance shell will now be started.
>   CONTROL-D will terminate this shell
>   and retry. myusername@root:~$

After searching in google,i found out that i have to run the command `fsck` on the OS partition from Ubuntu Live CD..

Here are my questions:

1. I don't know in which partition my Ubuntu OS is installed..(Those are not user-friendly drive names to remember right :)) -- Is there any command to know in which partition my Ubuntu OS is installed?
2. Can i do this from Ubuntu 10.04 live CD?

EDIT:

First, when i booted the live CD(10.04) and opened the file system, I don't see the UUID in the title.. And one more thing that `/etc/fstab` file has just three lines : 1) aufs /aufs rw 0 0 2) tmpfs /tmp nosuid,nodev 0 0 3) /dev/sda7 swap swap defaults 0 0  I don't know what to do..can u help me

Here are the screen shots:

[image][image]

Comment: Actually it's more likely that one of your filesystems has changed its address somehow. Boot a live CD (9.10 or above, 10.04 is fine), and report the output of `sudo fdisk -l`. Also report the contents of `/etc/fstab` (you'll probably have to change a line in that file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found is to run the `fsck` command and then it asked for confirmation pressed <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>..

Thats all. My system is working.

I found this solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305434

danizmax, the `/etc/fstab` file has the same UUID as the filesystem. I dont know why it failed.

Answer (score 2):

I think Gilles is right... in that case you just need to remap your disks with their new UUIDs.

- boot up your live CD
- open Nautilus and check which partition has similar folders to the picture below

[image]

You can see the partitions UUID in the title, if you wanna know what device this is...

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+T to open Terminal and enter `df -h`

[image]

then find the device with same UUID...

- now enter `sudo -H gedit /media/<your UUID>/etc/fstab`

[image]

replace your old UUID with your new one, make sure that you are replacing the right line in fstab. You can do this by checking if there is only `/` after the UUID.

You can same for your home as well, the only difference is, that you have to find your home directory and make sure that you are replacing the line with `/home`.

good luck!

Comment: Can u explain this `replace your new UUID with your old one`, I dont remember the old one.

Comment: haha I wrote it wrong :D it should be "replace your old UUID with your new one". Have corrected the text :P

Comment: did the guide help?

Comment: danizmax, I edited the question..can you look at the screen shots..I follwed what u said,But it is not working

Comment: You are opening the wrong fstab file. Because you are booting the live CD, you opened the one from the CD. You see, when you boot Live CD the root (/) is not on your disk but on CD. So You must open the one from the disk instead. In the last screenshot, you can see: sudo gedit /media/<here-comes-your-UUID>/etc/fstab. Check my screenshots carefully again and you'll get it :P

Comment: I forgot to attach the screen shot of file manager..I am not able to see the UUID as you mentioned..I am just getting the title as home and etc..How to get UUID

Comment: I am surprised, why i am not getting the UUID in the title of the window..